# Insight.Database Auto Interface & Mapping Many-to-Many

Tags: c#, insight.database

Assuming I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Game
(
  GameId INT,
  Name VARCHAR(50)
)

CREATE TABLE UserGameJoin
(
  GameId INT,
  UserId INT
)

CREATE TABLE User
(
  UserId INT,
  Username VARCHAR(50)
)
```

And the following classes:

```
public class Game
{
  public int GameId {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public List<User> Users {get;set;}
}

public class User
{
  public int UserId {get;set;}
  public string Username {get;set;}
}
```

How would I go about mapping results from this stored procedure

```
CREATE PROC GetGamesAndUsers
AS
SELECT *
FROM Game

SELECT GameId, u.*
FROM Game g
INNER JOIN UserGameJoin j ON j.GameId = g.GameId
INNER JOIN User u ON u.UserId = j.UserId
```

to an auto interface implementation?

```
public interface IGameLibrary
{
  List<Game> GetGamesAndUsers();
}
```

I've played around with the Recordset attribute by adding

```
[Recordset(1, typeof(User), Id = "GameId", IsChild = true)]
```

But when calling connection.As() an InvalidOperationException is thrown: "Sequence contains no matching elements."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had it right, but it looks like there's a bug when the interface returns a List instead of an IList and you specify the Id field.

If you return an IList instead, the call should work.

```
public interface IGameLibrary 
{
  [Recordset(1, typeof(User), Id = "GameId", IsChild = true)]
  IList<Game> GetGamesAndUsers();
}
```

I've opened this as issue #136 and it will be fixed in v4.2.7.

https://github.com/jonwagner/Insight.Database/issues/136

Comment: That works! Thank you for the quick response & resolving the issue.